# Why does Arquillian crash after adding htmlunit to POM?

Tags: jboss7.x, testng, jboss-arquillian

I am using Arquillian and TestNG under JBoss AS 7 to test a Maven project, and it worked just fine. After I added **htmlunit** to my POM like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Arquillian tests started crashing immediately with the following error:

```
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeSuite arquillianBeforeSuite
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create new instance of class org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:160)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:111)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:97)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.TestRunnerAdaptorBuilder.build(TestRunnerAdaptorBuilder.java:52)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.testng.Arquillian.arquillianBeforeSuite(Arquillian.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:564)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:277)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:156)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xml/serializer/TreeWalker
    at org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTransformer(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:823)
    at __redirected.__TransformerFactory.newTransformer(__TransformerFactory.java:133)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptor.spi.node.dom.XmlDomDescriptorExporterImpl.to(XmlDomDescriptorExporterImpl.java:66)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptor.spi.node.NodeDescriptorExporterImpl.to(NodeDescriptorExporterImpl.java:55)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptor.spi.node.NodeDescriptorExporterImpl.to(NodeDescriptorExporterImpl.java:30)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptor.spi.node.dom.XmlDomDescriptorExporter.to(XmlDomDescriptorExporter.java:51)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptor.spi.node.dom.XmlDomDescriptorExporter.to(XmlDomDescriptorExporter.java:34)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptor.spi.node.NodeDescriptorImplBase.exportTo(NodeDescriptorImplBase.java:55)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptor.spi.DescriptorImplBase.exportAsString(DescriptorImplBase.java:84)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.config.impl.extension.ConfigurationSysPropResolver.resolveSystemProperties(ConfigurationSysPropResolver.java:54)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.config.impl.extension.ConfigurationRegistrar.loadConfiguration(ConfigurationRegistrar.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.start(ManagerImpl.java:261)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.<init>(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:56)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xml.serializer.TreeWalker
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 49 more
```

My knowledge about JBoss and Maven is limited, but it appears that the problem is that **htmlunit** has a dependency on **xalan**, which is apparently also used by Arquillian, but I don't know why that messes things up. Any ideas?

Comment: Most likely they depend on different versions of the XML library (xalan). You could try mvn dependency:tree go get a complete dependency "graph" of your project. If you also do mvn -X dependency:tree you will get information which versions where discarded in favour of another. If you post the complete pom.xml we might be able to give you more detailed information.

Comment: @Peter Liljenberg: No, they use the same version, but your comment did lead me to a solution, which I will post as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the archive **serializer-2.7.1.jar**, which is a part of **xalan**, is packaged incorrectly (it cannot be unzipped) in JBoss Maven repository. Errors like these are a real pain to debug as there is no error message which points to the actual problem (thanks, Java). Anyway, I resolved the problem by copying the same archive from JBoss installation to local Maven repository.

Comment: There should be an error message if you use maven with debug option (`mvn -X`). Did you test that? Though you should probably use maven central if possible, most JBoss artifacts are there.